# Virtualbox has a Hyper-V backend. How do I enable nested virtualization using this backend?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, hyper-v

Virtualbox has its own [nested virtualization](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=90831) - currently (version 6.0 2019) only for AMD based virtualization.

However when Hyper-V is enabled, it can't use it's own virtualization, because Hyper-V takes exclusive access to VT-x/AMD-V so it [uses Hyper-V as a fallback to start the virtual machine](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=90853), instead of it's own.

Hyper-V does support [nested virtualization](https://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/enable-nested-virtualization/) as well. How do I direct Virtualbox to start the virtual machine with Hyper-V's nested virtualization enabled?

[Edit]: Notice, I am not asking about [exposing a para-virtualization interface to the guest](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch10.html#gimproviders), I am asking about nested VT-x/AMD-V virtualization. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You don't.  It's confusing, but that's not what this means.
VirtualBox uses the Hyper-V API in Windows and the KVM API in Linux VMs.   It's for the guest OS rather than the host.
Per VirtualBox documentation:

*Exposing a paravirtualization provider to the guest operating system does not rely on the choice of host platforms.* ...and...

*Oracle VM VirtualBox's implementation currently supports paravirtualized clocks, APIC frequency reporting, guest debugging, guest crash reporting and relaxed timer checks. This provider is recommended for Windows guests.*

From: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch10.html#gimproviders

Comment: Sorry, I know it's confusing, since there are so many different permutations of options. But my question is not about exposing a paravirtualization provider to the guest at all. Instead I have a Windows 10 host, that has Hyper-V active, in order to provide WSL2 functionality. Therefore the VirtualBox host can only use Hyper-V backend to run it's VM guests. And then for the VM guests I want to enable Hyper-V's nested virtualization feature. That is nested HW accelerated VT-X. Not para-virtualization.

Comment: @essjae Please refer to the [VirtualBox 6.0 changelog](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog-6.0#v0). VirtualBox can now use the [Windows Hypervisor Platform](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/api/) instead of its own virtualization engine.

Comment: @DanielB, yes, that's true, but it doesn't work, bug report for this: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/18387

Comment: Whether it (currently) works or not is not the question here. // Judging from your answer it appears you misinterpreted the question.

Comment: Thank you all for the input and the link to the Hyper-V bug report! Very interresting. I would love to get a helpful answer and I am happy to provide more feedback and change the question with more detail. But let's stop down-voting. That's a bit too harsh. Thanks again!